# Why these two errors are not equal

Tags: go

I create a err in my package and compare it with io.EOF, but the == operand is false. But their type and value are same? Why == operand return false?

```golang
func TestErr(t *testing.T) {
    err := errors.New("EOF")
    t.Log(err == io.EOF)
    t.Logf("io err:%T,%v,%p", io.EOF, io.EOF, io.EOF)
    t.Logf("my err:%T,%v,%p", err, err, err)
}
```

These two error are not equal because their pointers are not equal

Comment: From the documentation: "New returns an error that formats as the given text. Each call to New
    returns a distinct error value even if the text is identical." The documentation consists of two short sentences of which the second is the answer to your question. It is worth consulting the official documentation first and reading it all.

Answer (score 6):

`error` is an interface. It contains a pointer to the underlying value. The `io.EOF` is created by:

```
var EOF = errors.New("EOF")
```

If you look at `errors.New`:

```
func New(text string) error {
    return &errorString{text}
}

type errorString struct {
    s string
}
```

So, the `io.EOF` points to an instance of `errorString` struct, and the error you created also points to an instance of `errorString` struct with the same string value, but the two pointers are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, you can unwrap the errors:

```
package main

import (
   "errors"
   "io"
)

func main() {
   err := errors.New("EOF")
   println(err.Error() == io.EOF.Error())
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/builtin#error